# Python transform list of x,y and z to matrix/table

Tags: python, python-2.7, matrix, export-to-csv

I have list of format:

```
[[x_0, y_0, z_0], [x_1, y_1, z_1] ... [x_n, y_n, z_n]]
```

where can be x_0 == x_1:

```
[[0, 0, z_0], [0, 1, z_1], [0, 2, z_2]... [1, 0, z_o] ... [x_n, y_n, z_n]]
```

I want to transform it to the matrix like this (it would be nice to create the csv file):

[image: matrix]

The main problem - i don't know the total size of array (it will be changed every time, but it always will be square).
What is most easiest way to make this type of transformation?

The list is the XYZ coordinates for points.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how a three-by-N sized list of lists becomes a 17-by-17 matrix? Especially since 17 doesn't evenly divide 3. What input values correspond to what output values?

Comment: @Kevin for n=16 this will work. Whats the problem ?

Comment: Oh, I see. The X and Y values are integer indices of the resulting matrix. I thought he was trying to do something like pack [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]] into a 3x3 square where `a` through `i` are cell values.

Comment: No one has ever done anything like this, that's why it is going to work.

Comment: @Kevin Assume it as XYZ coordinates for points.

Comment: so x and y are the coordinates and z is the value?  Are you simply wanting a dump to a csv file or do you need to work with the data in the new format?

Comment: @SurestTexas Just to dump to a csv file

Comment: @XuMuK I know you have already accepted an answer, but 1) is you CSV supposed to contain headers and line numbers and 2) are you interested in a solution using only standard library or are you happy with the pandas solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use pandas to create a pivot table.  A pivot table lets you take data in row format and rearrange it into row, column, and values.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

# create some fake data

data = [(i,j,0.1*random.randrange(1,50,1)) for i in range(5) for j in range(5)]

# [(0, 0, 4.2), (0, 1, 1.9), (0, 2, 1.2), (0, 3, 1.2), (0, 4, 1.6),
#  (1, 0, 2.0), (1, 1, 0.9), (1, 2, 3.5), (1, 3, 3.0), (1, 4, 0.8),
#  (2, 0, 4.9), (2, 1, 2.8), (2, 2, 1.8), (2, 3, 2.7), (2, 4, 0.2),
#  (3, 0, 3.0), (3, 1, 1.8), (3, 2, 0.3,  (3, 3, 3.3), (3, 4, 4.4),
#  (4, 0, 1.9), (4, 1, 4.5), (4, 2, 3.6), (4, 3, 0.4), (4, 4, 0.4)]

# read it into a dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x','y','z'])

# create pivot table with x and rows, y and columns, z as values
df.pivot_table(values='z', index='x', columns='y')

# y    0    1    2    3    4
# x
# 0  4.2  1.9  1.2  1.2  1.6
# 1  2.0  0.9  3.5  3.0  0.8
# 2  4.9  2.8  1.8  2.7  0.2
# 3  3.0  1.8  0.3  3.3  4.4
# 4  1.9  4.5  3.6  0.4  0.4
```

Comment: It almost working, but it creates not the solid table (for example 12x12, but 12x5, than another 12x5 and 12x2...) How to make solid table 12x12?

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas and numpy

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

lis = [[0,0,3.4],[0,1,5.6],[1,0,4.3],[1,1,3.4]]

n2 = len(lis)
n = int(math.sqrt(n2))

nparray = np.zeros([n,n])

for l in lis:
    nparray[[l[0],l[1]]]=l[2]

print nparray
#[[ 4.3  4.3]
# [ 3.4  3.4]]

#Output to csv
df = pd.DataFrame(nparray)
df.to_csv('/some/path')
```

Comment: this is also working code, but another is a little bit simpler

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to stick with the standard library, this is one method.  Create a dictionary out of your data, then use the dictionary keys as a method to order the contents into a CSV format; finally write the CSV file:

```
# Data = your data formatted as described
resultsdict = {}
csvfile = ""
counter = 0

# create tuple-paired key dictionary of values (i.e. (0,0): 1.2, etc)
for pairs in data:
    if pairs[0] > counter:
        # track the square size
        counter = pairs[0]
    currentpairkey = (pairs[0], pairs[1])
    resultsdict[currentpairkey] = pairs[2]

# create raw CSV data
count = range(counter + 1)
for x in count:
    row = []
    for y in count:
        currentpairkey = (x, y)
        # this line is where you control your desired formatting.
        row.append("%s" % (resultsdict[currentpairkey]))
    print(row)
    csvfile += "%s\n" % ",".join(row)

# write CSV file
with open("results.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(csvfile)
```